# NGINX - URL argument rewriting

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I'm trying and failing to rewrite the following URL with nginx :

> https://mywebsite/myservice/pages/service/service.html?URL=/eServiceCNX/eservice.dll

to

> https://mywebsite/myservice/pages/service/service.html?URL=/eService/eservice.dll

Basically I'm trying to remove the "CNX" part from the "URL=" argument.

How can I do that ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several solutions, and they all use an `if` rather than a `rewrite` as the latter cannot operate on argument strings.

If this is the one and only URI that needs to be redirected, the simplest solutions is:

```
if ($request_uri = /myservice/pages/service/service.html?URL=/eServiceCNX/eservice.dll ) 
{ 
    return 301 /myservice/pages/service/service.html?URL=/eService/eservice.dll; 
}
```

The `$request_uri` variable contains the original request, including the arguments. See [this caution](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) on the use of `if`.

---

There are increasingly generalised solutions that make use of regular expressions to capture parts of the URI and reconstruct it without the "CNX" text present. But it really depends on your requirements.

For example, to modify any URI with an argument list containing "CNX":

```
if ($args ~ ^(.*)CNX(.*)$ ) { return 301 $uri?$1$2; }
```