# Nginx rewrite issue with question mark in between URL

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I need to forward URL `https://www.example.com/change/candidate/run/registration/?action=preregister` to `https://www.example.com/change/contact/us/` and for this I have defined this redirect rule as follows

```
# Redirects to handle all of the URL patterns from the old site 
rewrite ^/lang/candidate/run/registration/?action=preregister$  https://www.example.com/change/contact/us/ permanent;
```

but due to question mark in between it is not working.

Comment: Try [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/991255/nginx-url-argument-rewriting/991257#991257).

Comment: @RichardSmith Thanks but what if I don't want to use if condition? what would be my syntax then?

Comment: Your options are limited when testing URI+arguments. If you have a number URLs to redirect, you can simplify the solution with a `map`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49191594/nginx-rewrite-a-lot-2000-of-urls-with-parameters/49192527#49192527) on SO, but you still need an `if` to evaluate the map variable.